# SQL Server : update/swap multiple fields in multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008, ~1 million rows in `dbo.VDATA`

Table `dbo.VDATA`

```
PARTNO                 UDL3           ........
'100 - TXT'        '31OZ'
'101 - TXT'        '32 OZ'
```

Table `dbo.VDAT_AUX`

```
PARTNOAUX            UDL12          ........
'100 - TXT'               ''
'101 - TXT'               ''
```

What I need to accomplish:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.VDATA 
WHERE (PARTNO LIKE '% - TXT')

for each row in dbo.VDATA
set @Var_PARTNO-TEMP = PARTNO
set PARTNO = UDL3 & ' - TXT'
       ##Add ' - TXT' and set as PARTNO value
set dbo.VDAT_AUX.UDL12 = (REPLACE @Var_PARTNO-TEMP, ' - TXT', '')
       ##Remove ' - TXT' and set as UDL12 value
set dbo.VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX = dbo.VDATA.PARTNO
```

Example of desired result:

Table `dbo.VDATA`

```
PARTNO                 UDL3           ........
'31OZ - TXT'               '31OZ'
'32 OZ - TXT'             '32 OZ'
```

Table `dbo.VDAT_AUX`

```
PARTNOAUX            UDL12          ........
'31OZ - TXT'         '100'      
'32 OZ - TXT'          '101'
```

I'm able to select the rows I want, but I'm pretty lost on how to step through and shuffle the data how I need it... Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

This us my guess based on the info:

```
UPDATE vaux
SET UDL12 = REPLACE(v.PARTNO, ' - TXT', ''),
    PARTNO=v.UDL3,
    PARTNOAUX=v.PARTNO
FROM dbo.VDATA AS v
JOIN dbo.VDAT_AUX AS vaux ON v.PARTNO=vaux.PARTNOAUX
WHERE v.PARTNO LIKE '% - TXT'
```

The last set 'PARTNOAUX=v.PARTNO' may just be not required -- as the JOIN wouldn't work if the value wasn't already correct.

Clearly ... you want to try this on some test data, not the live.